Javascript: within a document that's been opened by another document, script within script
I am learning javascript on my own (I've been programming in python and C/C++ for a while).
I am building a project that displays family photos stored on a local server. The homepage has a search bar, which opens a new page with thumbnails returned with the results of the search.  I want a user to click on the thumbnail, which opens a new page with the image in full, displays the tags, and then has a form which allows a user to submit a possible correction for the tags.
I am unable to get the script that submits the correction for the tags to work properly - I expect it has to do with a document.write() containing another document.write() - the second of which has a script within a script.
my openTabWithThumbnails function is like this:
(setup and check for new tab opening omitted)
    newTab.document.write(`
    <html>
        <head>...</head>
        <body>
        <script>
        document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail.img'.forEach( => {
            (setup some vars)
            const imageTab=window.open('','_blank');
            if (imageTab) {
                imageTab.document.write(\`
                    <html>
                    <head>...</head>
                    <body>
                        (display image)
                        (build suggestion form)
                        !!problem starts here
                        '<scr' + 'ipt>'
                            (get data and send to server)
                        '<\scr' + 'ipt>'
                   </body>
                   </html>
                \`);
                imageTab.document.close();
              }
        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
     `); 
     newTab.document.close();`

I have also tried for the inner script:
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>');
        (get data and send to server)
    document.write('<\scr' + 'ipt>');


Also tried:
    var newscr = document.createElement('script');
    newscr.src='otherscriptfile.js';
    document.write('newscr.outerHTML');


In all cases I get the suggestion form up, but then the rest until  is displayed at the bottom of the second page.
I am sure I am missing something simple. I also understand that there is likely a much better way to do what I want to do - I've searched but likely am asking the question improperly

Do you really have backslash before the backticks, or was that added by the Stacks Editor in the New Question wizard?

@Barmar yes I do have the backslash before the interior backticks, otherwise, it would be considered the end of the previous opening backtick

@Yogi do you know of an example that uses the method suggested?

Oh, I didn't realize you had nested backticks.

It's the normal way to do navigation. Instead of using window.open(), use a link like <a href="show_image?id=${img_id}" target="_blank">Open image</a>

You're writing '<scr' + 'ipt>' to the document and that is not valid HTML. Why are you using '<scr' + 'ipt>' instead of just '<script>' ? In any case, you should just be using <script> without the quotes or string concatenation like you've done for all the other HTML tags.

if I use  to close the inner script, the outer one gets closed even though the inner one is written to the new document.  I looked at ways to break it up - some of those ideas that I tried were suggested on various other questions here on stackoverflow as ways to embed a script within a script
